# Highlighting a line in program listings in lyx

Tags: lyx

I am not able to find how i can highlight a particular line of code in program listings.
Syntax highlighting seems to work but I dont need particular language keywords to be highlighted.

e.g.
for the code below how can i highlight/bold face char j=malloc......line

```
public static void function(){
    int i=0;
    char j = malloc(sizeof(char));
    /.......some code....
    return;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you know the package `listings`? I am sure, there is support for this in `lyx` too. You should be more specific and provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer LyX uses `listings` by default when one does Insert --> Program listing, so the question is more how to this with `listings`, in LyX.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I don't use `lyx` at all...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer What i know is listings package is by default installed in lyx 2.0.6 but highlighting a particular line of code  to show it as an interesting event in program listing is not mentioned afaik

Comment: Idea: one could use LaTeX escape in the listing: somehow, you need to add `escapechar=@` (or perhaps another character, remembering to escape special ones) and then issue a `@\color{blue}@` at the beginning of the line you wish to highlight.  Can't test right now though...

Comment: I don't know the full answer to your question, but this might help convert a LaTeX solution into a LyX one: (1) to add settings to the listing environment, right click on it and choose "settings" and then go to the advanced tab; (2) you don't need use Insert->TeX for LaTeX in listings, you can just type it straight in; (3) to add things to your preamble, use the menu item Document->Settings and click on the preamble item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\hilight}{\makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \color{yellow}\rule[-4pt]{0.65\linewidth}{14pt}}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,escapechar=\%]
public static void function(){
    int i=0;
    %\hilight%char j = malloc(sizeof(char));
    /.......some code....
    return;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Adapted from an answer by [Juanjo on latex-community.org](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2835).

You can see the result [on writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/read/jztzdvcshrfj).

To achieve the same result in LyX, go to `Document->Settings` and navigate to the `Preamble` tab. Paste everything from `\usepackage{listings}` to the end of the `\begin{document}` block into the preamble and save it.

To insert the program listing into the document, go to `Insert -> Program Listing` in the menu. Paste the code into the listing environment. Then hold `Ctrl` and right-click on the environment and open the `Settings` dialog. Go to the `Advanced` tab in the dialog and paste `escapechar={\%}` into the text area. Configure the other settings however you want them to look.

There is an example LyX file you can download [here]
(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/9dfqtsc0fnftggc/hilite_example.lyx).

Comment: thanks for the example but actually i am looking for a way in which i can do the line highlighting while working on lyx document itself. I think i am too lazy to edit the latex document for it, that is the whole purpose of using lyx afaik. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I gave you the whole document to (hopefully) make it clear where everything goes, but there is no reason not to do this in LyX. Put the stuff before `\begin{document}` in your preamble and the `\begin{lstlisting}...\end{lstlisting}` part in a LaTeX box within your document.

Comment: I am afraid that when i incorporated your new command function in my document the highlighting is not happening. I followed what you have explained. in my pdf instead i can  see the actual command %hilight%char j........

Comment: I think your issue is with LyX and how to use some of its features. I have added more detail to the answer and an example LyX file.

Comment: If this has answered your question in full, please can you accept the answer? If not, is there anything specific that is still problematic for you?

Comment: @DamanjitSingh Did the updated answer solve your problem?

Comment: @snim2 Pardon me for late reply. Thanks for the solution. it did work.

Comment: The link to the sample LyX file is broken...